# How to add several domain names?

Tags: google-workspace, email, g-suite-administrator, g-suite-business

I signed up for [Google Apps for Businesses](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/), paid (I guess) $5 a month for this service. My primary goal is to use Google Apps for email accounts for my projects (with custom domains). I added one custom domain, everything is working well.

I need to add another two custom domains, but I don't see an option to do that.

How to tackle this situation?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Probably you should look at this. http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps accounts allow you to define one ore more "**domain aliases**" (inside the "Domains" area of the Admin Console), to simultaneously associate additional domains, for no additional fee. See the [documentation](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295&topic=14592&ctx=topic) for details.

Thus, if your Google Apps account was initially set up with a single domain and one paid user named 'user**A**@domain**1**.com', you could then associate additional domain-aliases such that the very same mailbox could also be used with 'user**A**@domain**2**.com' and 'user**A**@domain**3**.com'.

Incidentally, Google Apps accounts similarly allow you to define one ore more "**user aliases**", to simultaneously associate additional email addresses for a given mailbox, for no additional fee.

Thus, continuing the previous example, you could create user-aliases 'user**B**' and 'user**C**' for 'user**A**', such that the very same mailbox could also be used with 'user**B**@domain**1**.com' and 'user**C**@domain**1**.com' (as well as 'user**B**@domain**2**.com' and 'user**C**@domain**2**.com',  and 'user**B**@domain**3**.com' and 'user**C**@domain**3**.com').

Comment: Can you create email boxes per each custom domain with no aditional cost?

Comment: See my recent edit to this answer.